# OneVsRestClassification with GridSearchCV in Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

When I tried to search the optimal `C` and `gamma` in rbf kernel SVM by:

```
params = dict(C = C_range, gamma = gamma_range)
clf = GridSearchCV(OneVsRestClassifier(SVC()),params, cv = 5)
```

It returns the error says `C` is not the parameter of `OneVsRestClassifier`. What  is the proper way to achieve the grid search on the parameters with multiclass SVM then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grid search uses a custom nested attribute syntax for this:

```
params = dict(estimator__C=C_range, estimator__gamma=gamma_range)
```

The name `estimator` corresponds to the `OneVsRestClassifier` constructor parameter. Note the double underscores.

Comment: @ChuNan: depending on the problem, it may be better, and it will learn smaller models. If it's too slow, try setting `n_jobs=-1` on the OvR wrapper.